# Force data relocation between workers on Dask?

Tags: python, dask

I am working with Dask Arrays. The data is read from parquet files as Dask DataFrame and I need to transform the data into column-wise arrays to accelerate certain computation. However, after rechunking, the data is located in a single worker and not able to scale to the entire cluster.

I read from other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013717/forced-or-explicit-data-rebalancing-with-dask-distributed) that Dask does not invoke rebalancing when the data size is fairly small. Nonetheless I need to perform sorting so forcing data relocation should be desirable. I did not find a suitable method to move data between workers and can anyone suggest?

[image: Rechunking]
[image: Data is located in a single worker]

Note: the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013717/forced-or-explicit-data-rebalancing-with-dask-distributed) shows it is viable to store the data as NPY files and read back. But it is a bit clumsy as the data is already in memory and all you need is just relocation.

Comment: Are you using a recent dask version?

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Yes, it's 2022.10

Comment: Hi @Fontaine007, could you give a little more details about your setup? How many workers and how many threads per workers? If needed, Dask should move the data between workers when executing the next part of your workflow. In the question you site, there is also a comment about client.rebalance() that you might try to use after persisting your data in memory.